# MySQL style for creating foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've searched a bit for this, but I actually haven't found what is the style conception in MySQL for creating a foreign key - in the create table definition or in an alter statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When to create foreign key:**

If at the time of table creation it is clear you that you need foreign key then do at the time of creation, but if you realize later then do it in alter.

**Best practices:** you can follow below practice, it is not must but you can get benefits-

```
constraint fk_tableName_colName foreign key (colName) references parent_table(referenced_col_Name) cascading if required
```

Note: As foreign key name must be unique, so it will help to maintain it.

**Points Need to remember:**

1. referenced table in parent table must be indexed (if primary key then no need as it will be indexed).
2. column in both tables (parent/child) must have same schema.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs on how to create foreign keys...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

When a foreign key gets added can be during the initial architecture of the application being built or it can be added later as the application evolves.

Comment: Thanks, my point was mostly what is the preferable way to do this

Comment: My point is that the info you need is in the docs ie creating a foreign key is there. What more do you need?

Comment: I'm wondering is it something like a convention to create foreign keys in the alter statement, because I see this in a lot of places. But I also see FK in the table definition. I know there's no difference in the end result. I just want to know what is the convention if there is such, or it is just a matter of choice.

Comment: So to understand that if we know that we have to have FK, there is no convention how to define it?

Comment: There's always a convention on how to define a foreign key given types etc. There's no definition on how to choose the correct foreign key based on  your data. Don't get me wrong there are always obvious candidates but sometimes if you have several to choose from it's application based.